# how to create linked hash map object for this json

Tags: java, android

I am trying to call an API using Retrofit in android. For this API I need the input parameter JSON object in proper sequence.

Only if I have the json in required sequence I get successful response from the API, otherwise it gives an error. To handle this issue I got one solution that is to first create a `LinkedHashMap` of input parameter then create the JSON of that `LinkedHashMap`. This way I'm acheaving the response from api.

but right now im confused how to create linkedHash map for below json

```
{
   "RequestXml": {
     "Authenticate": {
       "InterfaceCode": "1",
       "InterfaceAuthKey": "AirticketOnlineWebSite",
       "AgentCode": "MOS0000001",
       "Password": "KGBW5P"
     },
     "BookTicketRequest": {
       "TrackNo": "0$182967|4|1AO",
       "MobileNo": "9099776464",
       "AltMobileNo": "9898989898",
       "Email": "abc@gmail.com",
       "Address": "Test",
       "ClientRequestID": "",
       "Passengers": {
         "Passenger": [
           {
             "PaxSeqNo": "1",
             "Title": "Mr",
             "FirstName": "Savan",
             "LastName": "Test",
             "PassengerType": "A",
             "DateOfBirth": "01/12/1992",
             "PassportNo": "RTTTTGGBGB56356",
             "PassportExpDate": "01/12/2024",
             "PassportIssuingCountry": "IND",
             "NationalityCountry": "IND"
           }
         ]
       },
       "Segments": {
         "Segment": [ 
         {
           "TrackNo":"0$182967|4|1AO",
           "SegmentSeqNo": "1",
           "AirlineCode": "UK",
           "FlightNo": "888",
           "FromAirportCode": "BOM",
           "ToAirportCode": "DEL",
           "DepDate": "30/09/2019",
                "DepTime": "14:00",
                "ArrDate": "30/09/2019",
                "ArrTime": "16:00",
                "FlightClass": "E",
           "MainClass": "Y" 
         }
         ]
       },
      "AdditionalServices": {
       },
        "TotalAmount": "4735",
       "MerchantCode": "PAY9zJhspxq7m",
       "MerchantKey": "eSpbcYMkPoZYFPcE8FnZ",
       "SaltKey": "WHJIIcNjVXaZj03TnDme",
       "IsTicketing": "Yes"

     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that a request json which already has the correct order? Why don't you just use it? Why do you need it as a Map which retains the correct orders?

Comment: actually it is desired json which i want. when i triyng to create json with above sequence created json sequence is getting changed. so im creating linked hashmap then json of that linkedhashmap

Comment: What is the json library you are using for serializing?

Comment: im using Gson library